# If Uniswap's domain goes down, how can we remove our tokens from a Liquidity pool manually without a front end interface?

Tags: tokens, contract-invocation, uniswap, liquidity-provider

Let's assume Uniswap's domain and front end interface is taken down. How can I as a user manually remove my tokens from a liquidity pool? What do I need and todo?

Answer (score 1):

You can call the Uniswap's contracts directly. Specifically, you should call the `Router02` contract, which handles all the details.

Depending on your use case, you need to decide which function to call, since there are many variants. You can find the documentation at https://uniswap.org/docs/v2/smart-contracts/router02/

You will need some way to create a transaction from the right wallet which calls the Router contract's functionality. I think there is no fast&easy solution here - I would personally write some javascript script for it, utilizing ethers.js.

Comment: Just as a tip if you try doing this - test it with a small amount before trying to move everything.